# engulf text with double qoutation

Tags: regex

I have the following text:

```
Budget Cube Options: Read Only, Read/Write, Admin
```

I would like to convert it to:

```
'Budget Cube Options'= @('Read Only','Read/Write', 'Admin')
```

Comment: For this part `@('Read Only','Read/Write', 'Admin')` you're going to need the `\G` anchor and an engine that supports it, PCRE, Php, Perl, etc .. if doing it with a single replace. If not, you can do it in 2 steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP, you can achieve what you want with this regex:

```
(?:^([^:]*)|\K)[:,]\s+([^,]+)
```

- `(?:^([^:]*)|\K)` looks for the start of the line, followed by some number of non `:` characters, *or* the end of the previous match (`\K`)
- `[:,]\s+` looks for the `:` between the first text, or the commas between subsequent values, followed by some whitespace
- `([^,]+)` looks for some number of non-comma characters. This will match until a comma, or end of line

The regex captures the text before the `:` in group 1, and the values after the `:` in group 2. You can use it like this:

```
$string = 'Budget Cube Options: Read Only, Read/Write, Admin';
preg_match_all('/(?:^([^:]*+)|\K)[:,]\s+([^,]+)/', $string, $matches);
echo "'{$matches[1][0]}'= @('" . implode("','", $matches[2]) . "')";
```

Output:

```
'Budget Cube Options'= @('Read Only','Read/Write','Admin')
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/6398t)

Regex [demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/93o5Is/1)